# Vector2 types in Win2D drawing method inconsistency

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core, win2d

I'm making my first steps into the UAP world in Windows 10.

I'm trying to write a small app that displays graphics on an IoT / R-PI2-device using the Win2D library.

I have a drawing method that displays a single line:

```
private void Canvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
  var a = new System.Numerics.Vector2(10,10);
  var b = new System.Numerics.Vector2(100,100);

  args.DrawingSession.DrawLine(a,b,Colors.Yellow);
}
```

VS2015 community ed. IntelliSense is telling me that I'm supplying incompatible vector2-types with the arguments 'a' and 'b'. It's expecting Windows.Foundation.Numerics.Vector2 instead of System.Numerics.Vector2.

However, the program compiles and runs just fine on desktop as well as on the r-pi.

Parts of my app are based on [this tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Creating-a-Universal-App-in-VB/UWP-getting-started-with-win2d) where the method clearly takes `System.Numeric.Verctor2` arguments.

I read in another post, that there have been made changes to the API between Windows 8.1 and 10, as well as this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/issues/76).

I also imported the package mentioned in this post but it didn't change anything.

I don't know if this post has something to do with my problem but at least it mentions a problem with this two namespaces.

Why is IntelliSense highlighting this code as an error? Is there a bug in VS?

Am I doing anything wrong here?

The Project: https://github.com/chrisi/IoTCanvas

Some System / IDE Specs in case that is relevant:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00079
- Installed Version: Community
- Visual Basic 2015 00322-20000-00000-AA366
- Visual C# 2015 00322-20000-00000-AA366
- Visual C++ 2015 00322-20000-00000-AA366
- Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU 00322-20000-00000-AA366
- Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package 1.0
- JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2 Build 103.0.20150818.200216
- Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools 1.4
- NuGet Package Manager 3.2.0
- PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer 1.2
- SQL Server Compact &SQLite Toolbox 4.3.0
- Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps 14.0.23309.00 d14oob

Comment: I'm seeing no such issues when trying this.  This is moving quickly, be sure to look for update notifications.  And you'll need to post the content of your project file.

Comment: i've added some information about the project and the ide-version

Comment: Remove System.Numerics.Vectors from the References node of the project.  Rest looks good.  It might be Resharper that is confuzzled, I don't use it.

Comment: i had the problem already before i added the System.Numerics.Vectors. i also disabled resharper code inspection - with no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Numerics.Vectors ships with Windows 10 and you do not need to install it separately.

The reason you are seeing references to Windows.Foundation.Numerics is because Windows.Foundation.Numerics is the name of the WinRT type.  This is projected in .NET as System.Numerics.Vector2.  Other languages may project it differently - in C++/CX it is Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float2, for example.

I strongly suspect that you are running into an issue with ReSharper - see https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/issues/145.  The word from there is:

> This one is fixed in R#10 and the fix will be available in one of the next EAP builds.

Comment: i didn't have the chance to check this as i need resharper for other projects so i will have to live with this problem for now but the link to issue with Win2D was very informative.

Comment: Just installed the new Version of Resharper - Error is gone. Thanks again!